# Can't get the text from pdf

Tags: pdf, text, extract, text-extraction, pymupdf

When i try to parse the pdf, i can't get the content of pdf but getting random symbols and characters. What is the reason behind it? This should give the proper text.
I have tried using PyPDF2 also still can not get the text.

```
filename = "test2.pdf"
with fitz.open(filename) as f:
    for p in f:
        print("\n\n")
        print(p.get_text(sort=True))
```

Result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38nQi.png)
This type of result i get.

Comment: you should post the PDF in question as well, so the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: FYI: this question has been asked and answered on PyMuPDF's home page already!